# Adding serial number for column in datatable

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

hi want to create a datable with a column having serial number and i am making the datacolum dynamic with adding rows on button click, i need to generate a serial number , what chat i do for this scenario,

My jsf page

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{section2Bean.employeeList}"
                            var="emp" style="width:100%;">
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                               #{msg.lbl_serialNo}
                            </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{TnwrdBean.hrmsBean.hrmsSection9.serialNo}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                 #{msg.lbl_addRow}
                             </f:facet>
                                <div class="buttons">
                                <p align="center">
                                <h:commandButton id="addEduQualRow" type="submit" actionListener="#{section2Bean.addNewEmployee}"
                                value="+" />
                                </p>
                                </div>
                            </h:column>
                        </rich:dataTable>
```

**Section2Bean.java**

```
public class Section2Bean  extends BaseAction implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 32423545435345L;
List<Employee> employeeList;
List<Employee> employeetrainingList;
private boolean checkSelected;

public List<Employee> getEmployeeList() {
    return employeeList;
}

public void setEmployeeList(List<Employee> employeeList) {
    this.employeeList = employeeList;
}

public void addNewEmployee(ActionEvent event) {
    employeeList.add(new Employee(employeeList.size(), null));
    System.out.println(employeeList);
    for(int i = 1;i<=employeeList.size();i++){
    }
}

public void deleteNewEmployee(ActionEvent event){
    employeeList.remove(employeeList.hashCode());
}
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    employeetrainingList =new ArrayList<Employee>();
    employeeList.add(new Employee(1, ""));
}

public Section2Bean() {
}

public boolean isCheckSelected() {
    return checkSelected;
}

public void setCheckSelected(boolean checkSelected) {
    this.checkSelected = checkSelected;
}
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried to generate serial numbers? What are you expecting?

Comment: i need to add serial number to first column , but my code reflects in all column because its an integer and i think i should probably add a arraylist

Comment: can you post the Employee class too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your datatable**

```
<h:column rendered="#{section2Bean.showSerials}">
    #{section2Bean.getSerial(emp)}
</h:column>
```

**Your bean**

```
import java.util.UUID;

private Map<Employee, String> serials;
private boolean showSerials;
// getter

@PostConstruct 
public void init() {
    serials = new HashMap<>();
    for(Employee employee : ...) {
        serials.put(employee, newSerial());
    }
}

public String getSerial(Employee employee) {
    return serials.get(employee);
}

public void buttonClick(ActionEvent event) {
    // other logic?
    showSerials = true;
}

private String newSerial() {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
```

Comment: i tried but doesnt work , should i iterate with employee list in init method

Comment: Yep, normally you'd retreive these from another backing bean though that wasn't clear by your example.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a new field in you bean to hold the serial number. When you are populating your List with instances of the bean, give it an incremented value each time. So in your jsf, you can directly access the serial number property.

Comment: i tried that but it gets reflected in all values for serial number

Comment: @user1858826 you mean the same value gets reflected in all the rows ?

Comment: yes it gets reflected in all rows

Comment: Maybe i can point out where you are going wrong if you could share that piece of code.